# WildFly cannot find XMLSchema.dtd

Tags: jboss, xsd, wildfly, dtd

I have WAR that I am deploying to a WildFly 10.0.0.CR5 server.

When the WAR is packaged, under `WEB-INF/wsdl/dir/dir/` there is a WSDL, some XSD files, and an XMLSchema.dtd file. One of the XSDs, called `xml.xsd`, has the following at the top of the file:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE xs:schema PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XMLSCHEMA 200102//EN" "XMLSchema.dtd" >
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xml:lang="en">
```

When I deploy this WAR, it fails to deploy with the following exception:

```
Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."MyWar.war".INSTALL:
org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."MyWar.war".INSTALL:
WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "MyWar.war"

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBWS024076: Service
{http://my.co.com/2011}MyService, cannot publish wsdl to: 
/jboss/wildfly-10.0.0.CR5/standalone/data/wsdl/MyWar.war/dir/wsdl/MyWsdl.wsdl

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
/jboss/wildfly-10.0.0.CR5/XMLSchema.dtd (No such file or directory)
```

Looking under `/jboss/wildfly-10.0.0.CR5/standalone/data/wsdl/MyWar.war/dir/wsdl`, I don't see the `XMLSchema.dtd` file, but it is included in the WAR that I'm trying to deploy in the `standalone/deployments` folder.

Removing the `<!DOCTYPE xs:schema PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XMLSCHEMA 200102//EN" "XMLSchema.dtd" >` line fixes the issue, but I'm looking for a solution where I don't have to do that.